# QSqlQuery addBindValue одинарные кавычки вместо NULL

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Имею следующий код:

```
QString text;    
if ( Условие, которое в нашем случае возвращает false )
    text = "Некий текст";

QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO shop (`name`) VALUES (?)");
query.addBindValue( text );
query.exec();
```

Получаем ошибку:

> Column 'name' cannot be null QMYSQL3: Unable to execute statement

Есть ли способ заставить QSqlQuery вставлять `''` вместо `null`?
В интернете много интересного на тему кавычек, но ответа на свой вопрос я не нашел. Может кто нибудь знает ответ?

Comment: А почему бы Вам самому этого не сделать? Всего-то одну строчку поменять: `QString text = "\""; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас странный вопрос. Фактически, если перефразировать, то получится: как мне заставить `QSqlQuery` вставлять "тра-та-та" вместо `NULL`? Очевидно, что это самое "тра-та-та" и следует подставить в метод `addBindValue()`, не выдумывая неких хитрых обходных путей. Ведь что пустая строка, что имеющая символы - это всё одно суть строка и со значением `NULL` не имеет равенства. В общем, просто инициализируйте переменную `text` пустым значением.

Comment: Как всё просто. :) Спасибо большое! И как я до этого сам не додумался. =)